# MongoDB is not getting connected even if mongod command showing "waiting for connections"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I don't know much about MongoDB. I downloaded MongoDB Community Server version 6.0.6. My node version is 18.15.0. I created a project folder on desktop and initialized npm and installed mongodb using npm i mongodb. When I run mongod cmd it shows "waiting for connections", but when i run node app.js it shows nothing.

My code:
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sCJ1.png)

First I run mongod command -
[after running mongod cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaQlV.png)

then i run node app.js, it shows nothing-(it just goes to next line and remains blank)[running node app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hp9TL.png)

Please help.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source of the [connect method](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/main/src/mongo_client.ts#L424), it does not accept a callback, at least in the newest version. It just returns a promise after connection to MongoDB Database was established.

You would have to await the promise of the connect method and access the database then.

```
client.connect().then(function() {
   console.log('connected')
   const collection = client.db(dbName).collection()
}
```