# can't retrieve data from my mongodb with node.js app

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

I am trying to retrieve a set of data based on given location, date, month and year from my mongodb. but for some reason it never seems to work.. here is my code in the index.js file:

I have obviously replaced the usernames and password in the uri...

```
const express = require('express');
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

const app = express();
const uri = "mongodb+srv://test:test@cluster0.test.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"; 

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello, world!');
});

app.get('/adhan', (req, res) => {
  const location = req.query.location;
  const date = req.query.date;
  const month = req.query.month;
  const year = req.query.year;

  MongoClient.connect(uri, (err, client) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Failed to connect to MongoDB Atlas:', err);
      res.status(500).send('Failed to connect to the database');
      return;
    }

    const db = client.db('times'); 
    const collection = db.collection('times'); 

    collection.findOne({ Location: location, Date: date, Month: month, Year: year }, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Failed to retrieve times:', err);
        res.status(500).send('Failed to retrieve times');
        return;
      }

      if (!result) {
        res.status(404).send(' times not found');
        return;
      }

      res.json(result);
    });

    client.close();
  });
});

const port = 3000;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

please help

i have tried using the browser with query:

http://localhost:3000/adhan?location=Aberystwyth&date=2&month=1&year=2023

And it doesnt do anything, just keeps on loading, and i even tried postman, with a GET service and it does the same thing, just keep loading until I close the port.

I am expecting it to return specific times based on the given location and dates.

Comment: Perhaps it's the callbacks?  Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76449653/1409374

Comment: ... https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/releases/tag/v5.0.0